# How to create new controller in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller-factory

Imagine an `MVC` project without any controller in that solution. I have same thing and want to create controller at runtime by using a `DefaultControllerFactory` then register it in my `Global.asax` by `Autofac`.
Here I have a sample controller factory which has `CreateController` method:

```
internal class CControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> _controllerMap;

    public CControllerFactory()
    {
        List<IController> lstControllers = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IController>().ToList();
        _controllerMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>>();

        foreach (Controller contr in lstControllers)
        {
            string ctrName = contr.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
            _controllerMap.Add(ctrName, c => contr);
        }
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {

        if (_controllerMap.ContainsKey(controllerName))
        {
            return _controllerMap[controllerName](requestContext);
        }
        else
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(controllerName);
    }
}
```

As you see above, this line: `List<IController> lstControllers = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IController>().ToList();` will get the list of controllers which use `IController` service. But in my case there is no controller exist in the solution. I want to create a new controller at run time and add it in my `_controllerMap`.

So I changed code to this:

```
internal class CControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> _controllerMap;

    public CControllerFactory()
    {
         // *Don't need this*
         // List<IController> lstControllers = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IController>().ToList();
        _controllerMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>>();
         // *Don't need this Foreach*
         // foreach (Controller contr in lstControllers)
         // {
               string ctrName = "Home";
               // But what about contr in this line?!?!:
               _controllerMap.Add(ctrName, c => contr);
         // }
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {

        if (_controllerMap.ContainsKey(controllerName))
        {
            return _controllerMap[controllerName](requestContext);
        }
        else
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(controllerName);
    }
}
```

So what about `contr` in specified line? This argument must to be type of `Func<RequestContext,IController>`. How can I create it functionally by C# code?

Comment: What is the requirement which causes you to create a new controller at run time? How are you planning to add action methods to the new controller and how about compiling the controller code so that CLR can execute it? What about routes?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya don't worry about Rout and Views(i fixed it by using a custom viewEngine). i just need to create a home controller with an Index ActionResult at run time. Is that possible in mvc?